# Conda package without python enviroment

Tags: python, docker, conda

I try to install a conda package into a docker image, but conda changes default python, that is needed, after instalation. How I can solve this problem?

Can I use conda to install a package not into env, but into default system?

Conda package: faiss

Docker image: apache/airflow

Now my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest-python3.8

# conda
USER root
COPY --from=continuumio/miniconda3:4.12.0 /opt/conda /opt/conda

ENV PATH=$PATH:/opt/conda/bin

RUN conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no && \
    conda install -c pytorch faiss-cpu
```

And it installes faiss, but not in default python, that is used by airflow.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to edit the .bashrc file to change the location of the interpreter which the `python` command points to. Suppose you want to use python3.10 as the python interpreter of your choice then:

```
$ #Get location of the python3.10 interpreter
$ which python3.10
```

The output would be something like `usr/bin/python3.10`. Now in your .bashrc file, append the following line:

```
python=/usr/bin/python3.10
```

NOTE: You need to reload your shell for the changes to take effect. Alternatively, you can also do `exec .bashrc` to load the env variables in your current shell.